# High Frequency financial data

Tags: time-series, finance-mathematics, financial

I really need high frequency data for my thesis. The data should contain the following columns:

Time with format: yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss;
Price;
Bid price;
Ask price;
Bid volume;
Aks volume;
volume

I tried several different online sources to get the data. The second best solution I found was the dakuscopy website, but they didn't contain the price and volume column which are crucial for my analysis. So pls help!

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60677/us-equity-real-time-market-data-feed-pricing - consolidated tape, quote feed.

Comment: Since you’re in university I advice you come up with a plan to get this data together with your professor.

Comment: You haven't specified what asset class you're looking for!

Comment: well that's the problem, my university has the tool data stream and the finest frequency I have access to is in minutes. This is already too coarse. I am looking for stock market data. Which Company is basically at this point secondary, as long as I get the needed columns and at least a couple of trading day. Only one would be to little but of course better then nothing

Comment: Maybe you can contact authors that have published using HF data or contact firms near you? Unfortunately I don’t think any HF data is downloadable from the open web. If it’s hopefully it will be linked in the linked question.